# Arduino/C++: Access specific header file of structs from library

Tags: c++, c, struct, arduino

(Not sure whether this is exclusively a C/C++ issue)

I’m currently fragmenting elements of a large Arduino project into reusable libraries - so far soo good.

However, a number of methods in the libraries return special structs which are declared in a `data-types.h` file contained in each library. The problem I have now is I'm unable to import/utilise these structs in my main sketch. I've tried declaring a variable of the `DataTypes` class in the main library header file and accessing the structs through it, but I get error `error: invalid use of 'struct DataTypes::_theStructNameHere_t'`

How would I go about accessing these structs from the library in my main sketch to declare as a variable type? I don't want to have to copy the header file which contains the structs from the library into my sketch, and I also don't want to have to create a separate library just for this single header file of structs!

Here's a quick example of what I mean:

#### Main.cpp:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <MyLibrary.h>

MyLibrary myLib;

void setup() {
    (This is declared in the library) myLib.dataTypes._theStructNameHere_t response = myLib.getASpecialValueWhichIsOfType_theStructNameHere_t()// Gives "error: invalid use of 'struct DataTypes::_theStructNameHere_t'""

    // Example usage of the struct:
    Serial.print("\n Loop Card Status: ");Serial.print(response.loop_status, HEX);
    if (response.number_allocated > 0) {
        Serial.print("\n Devices Allocated: ");Serial.print(response.number_allocated, HEX);
    } else {
        if (response.loop_status != 0x123) {
            // Some condition
        } else {
            // Something else
        }
    }
}

void loop() {
    ...
}
```

#### Library Structure:

```
    src/
    - /data-types/
    - - data-types.h
    - MyLibrary.cpp
    - MyLibrary.h
```

#### Library Header `MyLibrary.h`:

```
#ifndef   _MYLIBRARY_H_
#define   _MYLIBRARY_H_

#include <Arduino.h>

#include "./helpers/helpers.h"
...
#include "./data-types/data-types.h"

class MyLibrary {

    public:
        Uart *_commPort;
        Helpers helpers;
        ... 
        DataTypes dataTypes;

        DataTypes::_theStructNameHere_t getASpecialValueWhichIsOfType_theStructNameHere_t();

      ...

    protected:
    private:

};

#endif // _MYLIBRARY_H_
```

#### DataTypes Class `data-types.h`:

```
#ifndef   _RESPONSE_TYPES_H
#define   _RESPONSE_TYPES_H

class DataTypes
{
    public:
      struct _theStructNameHere_t
        {
            bool successful;
            uint8_t loop_status;
            uint8_t number_allocated;
            uint8_t highest_address;
            uint8_t number_inputs;
            uint8_t number_outputs;
        }
        ..even more..
    private:
}
#endif // _RESPONSE_TYPES_H
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to obtain a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from your example:

```
class DataTypes
{
    public:
    struct _theStructNameHere_t
    {

    };
};

class Library
{
    public:
        DataTypes dataTypes;
        DataTypes::_theStructNameHere_t getMyDataType();
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Library myLib;
    myLib.dataTypes._theStructNameHere_t response;
}
```

which gives a similar error as your code:

```
~$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cpp:20:21: error: invalid use of 'struct DataTypes::_theStructNameHere_t'
     myLib.dataTypes._theStructNameHere_t response;
```

The problem is that you use an instance to access the `struct` type/name. To fix it, replace

```
myLib.dataTypes._theStructNameHere_t response = ...;
```

with

```
DataTypes::_theStructNameHere_t response = ...;
```

---

**Notes:**

- Instead of using classes to create separate namespaces, please consider using **namespaces** directly. This is a feature of `C++` which is available under *Arduino*.

```
namespace Library {

namespace DataTypes {

struct _theStructNameHere_t
{
    ...
};

...

} /*** namespace Library::DataTypes ***/

} /*** namespace Library ***/
```